# python generating netaddr error when running code

Tags: python

I am trying to get a piece of software called [Probemon](https://gitlab.com/datrv4/probemon) working and have come up with an error when I try to run it.

As I have both python2 and python3 installed (as per default installation) so I am running the command:

```
root@root:~/probemon/src$ python2 ./probemon.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./probemon.py", line 11, in <module>
    import netaddr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from netaddr.core import (AddrConversionError, AddrFormatError,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from netaddr.compat import _callable, _iter_dict_keys
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/compat.py", line 93, in <module>
    import importlib_resources as _importlib_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._common import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/_common.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/_compat.py", line 42, in <module>
    from zipp import Path as ZipPath  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/zipp.py", line 217
    def open(self, mode='r', *args, pwd=None, **kwargs):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what this error is trying to indicate...

Prior to this I have run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr
cd netaddr
sudo python setup.py install
cd
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy.git
cd scapy
sudo python setup.py install
```

to ensure both netaddr and scapy dependencies are installed

To me, the error looks to have a problem with `line 11 import netaddr` however IF this is the case, I have already installed this, so I am not sure where the problem lies.

I have also tried running `sudo python setup.py install` for netaddr and scapy as `sudo **python2** setup.py install` in their respective directories just in case this made any difference which it did not.

Can anyone tell me what what the error is indicating please.

Thanks

Comment: this syntax is only supported by Python 3

Comment: @Marat Strangely the website says that this has been written in Python 2... Looks like I may need to convert this???

Comment: it isn't probemon itself, it is one of its dependencies, zipp. probemon probably didn't limit zipp to the right version, and zipp itself didn't declare Python version compatibility correctly. You might be able to fix this by manually reinstalling zipp to a lower version: `pip install zipp=1.2.0`